# Weird 403 Forbidden error

Tags: php, http-status-code-403

I am having a weird situation here.  This error comes only on one file in the directory and that too when the form is submitted. It works perfectly fine on my machine. But the server stubbornly throws up the error on form submit !

error:

```
Forbidden

You don't have permission to access /Myadmin/searchnsendmail2.php on this server.

Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.
Apache/2.2.24 (Unix) mod_ssl/2.2.24 OpenSSL/1.0.0-fips mod_auth_passthrough/2.1 mod_bwlimited/1.4 FrontPage/5.0.2.2635 Server at www.landshoppe.com Port 80
```

The code is here;

searchnsendmail2.php

```
<?php error_reporting(E_ALL);include('adminmaster.htm');?>
<div style="margin-left:250px;text-align:left">
<ul>
<li style="display:inline;padding:20px"> <a href="csvtodb.php"><font style="color:maroon">CSV Display/Upload</font></a></li>
    <li style="display:inline;padding:20px"> <a href="excel_reader/example.php"><font style="color:maroon">XLS Upload and Display</font></a></li>
    <li style="display:inline;padding:20px"> <a href="searchnsendmail2.php"><font style="color:maroon">Data Search/Mail</font></a></li>
</ul>
    <h2> Send Property Details by eMail to some one !</h2>
<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="POST">
<table width="900"><tr><td>Email Id :</td><td><input type="text" name="emailid" value="<?php if(isset($_POST['emailid'])){echo $_POST['emailid'];} ?>"></td></tr>
<tr><td>Address : </td>
<td><textarea name="address" cols="50" rows="5">Dear     ,<br><br>
Ref our telecon, please find below details of properties as discussed.</textarea><br>
<tr><td>Search word<br></td><td><input type="text" name="searchword" value="<?php if(isset($_POST['searchword'])){echo $_POST['searchword'];} ?>"></td>

<td>
Select Table<br><select name="ltable" id="ltable">
<option value="all" <?php if(isset($_POST['ltable']) && $_POST['ltable']=="all"){echo "selected";} ?>>All</option>
<?php 
include('conn.php');
mysql_select_db("landshop_dblist");
$query=mysql_query("SELECT dbname FROM dblist");
while($info=mysql_fetch_assoc($query))
{$dtable=$info['dbname'];?>
<option value="<?php echo $dtable;?>" <?php if(isset($_POST['ltable']) && $_POST['ltable']==$dtable){echo "selected";} ?>><?php echo $dtable;?></option><?php }?>
<option value="clientdata" <?php if(isset($_POST['ltable']) && $_POST['ltable']=="clientdata"){echo "selected";} ?>>clientdata</option>
</select>
</td><td>
<!-- &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
<span id="somef">Some Fields</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
<span id="allf">All Fields</span>-->
Show Fields<br>
<select name="show">
<option value="fall" <?php if(isset($_POST['show']) && $_POST['show']=="fall"){echo "selected";} ?>>All</option>
<option value="some" <?php if(isset($_POST['show']) && $_POST['show']=="some"){echo "selected";} ?>>Some</option>
</select>
</td>
<td>Show Contacts<br>
<select name="sconts" >
<option value="Yes" <?php if(isset($_POST['sconts']) && $_POST['sconts']=="Yes"){echo "selected";} ?>>Yes</option>
<option value="No" <?php if(isset($_POST['sconts']) && $_POST['sconts']=="No"){echo "selected";} ?>>No</option>
</select>
</td>

</tr>
<tr><td>Signature :</td><td> <textarea name="sign" cols="50" rows="5">Please do revert if you can process any of the below<br><br>
Thanks and Regards<br><br>Anit</textarea></td></tr>
<tr><td><input type="submit" name="mailsubmit" onclick="MakeLinkSafe()"></td></tr></table>
</form>
<?php include('searchresults.php');?>
</div>
```

searchresults.php is as follows;

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['mailsubmit']))
{

$searchword=$_POST['searchword'];
echo $searchword."<br><br>";
$searchword=str_replace(array(","," "),"|",$searchword);
$searchword=explode("|",$searchword);

$ar=array();
$pr=array();
$are=array();
$pri=array();
$prop=array();
$cust=array();

///SOME FIELDS ------------------------------------------
if($_POST['show']=="some"){

//all tables__________
if($_POST['ltable']=="all"){echo "Coming Soon !";exit;}

//tables other than clientdata____________
else{include('somefields.php');if(isset($_POST['dfsubmit'])){include('maildetails.php');}}
}

//ALL FIELDS ------------------------------------------------
elseif($_POST['show']=="fall"){

//all tables_______________
if($_POST['ltable']=="all"){include('alltables.php');echo $salltables;include('maildetails.php');}

//clientdata_______________
//elseif($_POST['ltable']=="clientdata"){include('clientdata.php');}

//Other tables
else{$salltables="";include('searchall.php');echo $salltables;include('maildetails.php');}
}
}
//-- ----------------------------------------------------------
?>
```

Comment: I'm not really an expert with PHP, but my guess is that it doesn't have much to do with the PHP itself, but with the permissions the PHP user on your server has or doesn't have.

Comment: It could also be the specific permissions of the file /Myadmin/searchnsendmail2.php

Comment: Is this code hosted on commercial host solution? Some hosting companies / solutions they use (like cPanel, direcAdmin, etc) have wierd rules, like a file is considered 'not found' by PHP if the file's group have write access, etc...

Comment: But I did not make any changes to any file or permissions or anything. Just uploaded like all other files ! Why only this file suddenly needs permissions ?!!!

Comment: Also why only on webserver and not on my machine ? Both have all the same settings I guess.

Comment: @Marcell I am not sure what a commercial host solution is. I am hosted on good.thehostingserver.com through 'webhostingjack'. But then again this file is in a folder which has other files of the same type and works !

Comment: Are other files that are accessible by PHP in the same folder have the same permissions? Do an `ls -la` in that folder and compare.

Comment: Also why on form submit only ?!!

Comment: Yes @Marcell, I believe all have the same permissions as I do not see any reason why it should change suddenly for a new file added. BTW sorry for this naive query...how do you do an `ls-la` on a folder ?

Comment: When you are on a command line just type it like:
`$ ls -la` ($ sign is the prompt, and there is a space between ls and -).

Comment: I have split the form and php into two files `searchnsendmail2.php` and  `searchresults.php`. Now it is saying `searchresults.php' is Forbidden !!

Comment: Beyond me..thanks anyways @marcell and everybody else

Comment: I just wanted to add a quick note that I've found that on my hosts setup, submitting the word "exit" as part of the form submission (TextArea) was guaranteed to return a 403 error.  I don't think this has always been the case, but thought this may save someone similar pain in the future.

Answer (score 3):

Solved ! The server didnt seem to like text in Textarea value with html characters being submitted !  I removed them and now alls well ! Thanks all !

I would also like to use this opportunity to highlight the fact that whenever I had googled for this issue, I have invariably always found people saying this is a permissions issue. It was so frustrating as I couldnt understand why suddenly only one file and one form was having a permissions issue.  I hope this example of mine lets all those who are frustrated with this issue(and those who offer permissions issue as answer) know that it can also be such an error as mine and look into it. Should save a lot of people a lot of time !

Answer (score 1):

Encountered the same error, but it was caused by the form length. I had a form which had hundreds of fields. Upon removing some of the fields, the form submitted successfully.

The form length had triggered a rule on mod_security. My app was on a shared hosting so a simple request to the hosting provider to bypass the rule solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I just experienced this error intermittently when submitting a php page containing the form... In my case the issue was a full /tmp directory on the server. Posting this here in case it helps someone else.